# Função não funciona depois de instalado o aplicativo

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova

Essa é a função que quando instalo nao funciona.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);//quando ele clicar no botao de voltar
}

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
  if (overlayVisible) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hideOverlay();
  }
  else {
    navigator.notification.confirm("Você deseja sair do aplicativo?", onConfirm, "Confirmação", "Sim,Não"); 
    // alerta de confirmação para sair do aplicativo
  }
}

function onConfirm(button) {
  if (button == 2) {//Se o usuario escolher nao simplesmente nao fara nada
    return;
  }
  else {
    navigator.app.exitApp();// Caso contrario sair do app.
  }
}
```

Comment: Quando faço o teste pela linha de comando do phonegap serve funciona normalmente mas depois de gerado o APK não funciona... Ajudem please!

Comment: Mas outras funções funcionam ou nenhuma função funciona depois de gerado o APK?

Comment: Todas as outras funcionam. até o if funciona, menos o else.

Comment: Qual else não funciona o do `onConfirm` ou o do `onBackKeyDown`. Você também pode me dizer mais sobre a váriavel `overlayVisible`? Se ela realmente altera seu estado em algum momento.

Comment: O else que não funciona é o do onBackKeyDown, quando eu testo ele pelo aplicativo do phonegap funciona normalmente porem quando instalo no dispositivo deixa de funcionar. O overlayVisible altera seu estado quando clico em alguma foto presente no aplicativo ela muda de false para true quando alguma imagem está aberta. Coloquei no [GitHub](https://github.com/bleekbless/ProjetoPi2.0/blob/master/projetopi/www/assets/touchTouch/touchTouch.jquery.js) o JS completo onde há essa função.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes na sua aplicação e realmente existe problemas. O que posso recomendar é que trate de forma diferente os eventos de finalização do aplicativo. Pelo que percebi você modificou um plugin `JS`adicionando códigos do Cordova a sua lógica, você deveria separar um pouco o que cada arquivo possui e faz, até mais para tornar o suporte mais fácil. Tentei fazer uma separação, porém ainda encontrei problemas. Faz alguma forma de delegação de eventos mais limpa. Qualquer coisa só me avisar que te dou um auxilio.